# How to make task2 execute after task1 finishes in swift ? use dispatch_sync?

Tags: swift, swift2

**ISSUE:**

I have two tasks : task1 and task2. I want to execute task2 after task1 finishes.

**MY CODE:**

```
let globalQueueDefault = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0)

dispatch_sync(globalQueueDefault){

    self.activityIndicatorView.hidden = false
    self.activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()

        task1()

        sleep(6)
        dispatch_sync(globalQueueDefault) { () -> Void in

            task2()                                             
        }
}
```

**EXPLANATION:**

task1 should download somethings from internet, so I use `sleep(6)` . I think this solution is not good because we can not be sure the internet will work.. So do you have a solution to send a signal to task2 after the end of task1 ? Thank you very much. !

My code for closure is like this

```
func getTheSearchLocationAndRange(completed: FinishedDownload) {
    Task1()
    completed()
}
@IBAction func loginAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    getTheSearchLocationAndRange { () -> () in
        Task2()
    }
}
```

Thank you !

Comment: Why arent you simply using callbacks?

Comment: @user2262304 If my answer solved your issue, could you please accept it ?

Comment: I am sorry for a little late to answer you, I need your help yet, but I have some things urgence to do these days(It is not me to decide this...), I will poste some code after, I hope you can help me after, Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### HOW  TO USE A SWIFT CLOSURE:

**REFERENCE:**

Please refer to the Apple guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html

---

**EXAMPLE:**

```
typealias FinishedDownload = () -> ()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    getTheSearchLocationAndRange()
}

func getTheSearchLocationAndRange(completed: FinishedDownload) {

       // Code for searching Location Range HERE

       completed()
}

getTheSearchLocationAndRange { () -> () in
    loadDataFromDatabase()
}
```

---

**EXPLANATION:**

1) FinishedDownload is the closure.

2) When `getTheSearchLocationAndRange()` is called, its code is executed until the `completed()` line which waits for all processes of the function to finish.

3) Once the processes finish (downloads for example), `completed()` calls the closure which activates the code defined in `getTheSearchLocationAndRange { () -> () in`.

4) Therefore, `loadDataFromDatabase()` is only called once `getTheSearchLocationAndRange()` has entirely finished executing and the data is present (not nil).

**EDIT:**

This is what you did:

```
func getTheSearchLocationAndRange(completed: FinishedDownload) {
    Task1()
    completed()
}
@IBAction func loginAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    getTheSearchLocationAndRange { () -> () in
        Task2()
    }
}
```

This is what you should have done:

```
typealias FinishedDownload = () -> ()

@IBAction func loginAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    Task1()
}

func Task1(completed: FinishedDownload) {
    //code for Task1
    completed()
}

Task1 { () -> () in
    Task2()
}
```

Comment: Definition typealias FinishedDownload can be removed and replaced by dispatch_block_t. 
Arguments from closure could be also removed: `getTheSearchLocationAndRange {
    loadDataFromDatabase()
}`

Comment: @JMI Thx for the feedback !

Comment: Hello, your code is very good, but I tried your code in my program, I think perhaps closure is not good for my program. The task1 need download from internet, but `loadDataFromDatabase()` works before download all of thing or get a answer from server. Do you have another solution ?

Comment: @user2262304 where did you put your code for task 1 ? Could you please update your question to show us how you implemented the code I gave you ?

Comment: @user2262304 I think there is  a mistake in there. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i doesn't work yet... I use json to ask down load the sources, I will update my question to show some code, thank you

Comment: Hello, I have fond a solution for this problem. and your callback is very perfect, so I support your answer. Thank you very much.